# Prove that the identity matrix applies in 4 x 4 alternate matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let invertible matrix A size 4 x 4 and let matrix B be the matrix that is the result of alternating the first two lines of A and adding in the fourth line the double amount of the third line. Is B an invertible matrix?

So, far I know that if an A intvertible matrix exists then 
AB = BA = In , where In is the identity matrix of A.

My question, is whether the above thought is correct and what steps should I follow in order to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is (more or less) correct -- a square matrix $M$ is invertible if there exists a matrix $N$ with $NM=MN=I$.

Have you tried calculating $B$? What does it look like? Can you reason about what the entries of $B^{-1}$ would have to be to get $BB^{-1}=I$?

Note that there are many alternative ways of solving this problem, if you have learned more sophisticated linear algebra (determinants, elementary row operations, etc).

Comment: I haven't yet learned determinants. My thinking is that I have to convert B to A^-1. So, if A has ,say {{1,1},{-1.2}.{3.1},{3,2}} then B will be somewhat like {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f},{g,h}}. Then I will do some calculation in order to complete the identity matrix.Does this make sense?

Comment: If you've learned about elementary row operations and their inverses, using them here is definitely a good approach.